# Incorrect slashes in java path

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I am trying to run unit tests for an Android application using Robolectric, via Android Studio. However, whenever I run the tests I get the following error:

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60/bin/javac''

Notice that the path uses backslashes for the first half, and **forward** slashes for the second half. I'm running Windows 8, so I believe these the forward slashes are the cause of the issue. However, I'm unable to find *where* these slashes are coming from.

I've run these tests on another Windows 8 computer, and they work there, so I'm convinced it's a local issue. I've checked all locations I can think of which might be define this path - Gradle files, system environment variables, Android Studio project settings - and they're all using the correct (back) slashes. I've also tried reinstalling Java and Android Studio, and deleting and replacing my local copy of the project, but no luck.

Where else should I check, or what else should I try?

**Edit** I was using jre1.8.0_65 but had the path set to _60. This has been corrected, but I still get the same error (now referring to _65).

Comment: windows environment?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira do you mean the environment variables? I have checked those, and they appear in order.

Comment: The mixed delimiters are not *necessarily* the problem, and may be normal.  (Under most circumstances, Windows will not object.)  Have you checked whether the path is otherwise correct?  For example, perhaps you have Java 8u65 installed, so the path should be pointing to it?

Comment: @Harry Johnston huh, you were right, I did have 8u65 installed. How embarrassing. However, I'm still getting the same error after correcting the path (the error now refers to "jre1.8.0_65"), so my original question still stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that AndroidStudio is trying find the javac.exe file in the jre's bin folder. jre/bin folders does not contain the javac.exe file, jdk/bin does. So I'm guessing you incorrectly setup the environment variable. Posting them would help fix the issue.

Comment: Yep, my "JAVA8_HOME" environment variable was pointing to the jre instead of the jdk. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I guess the forward slashes were a red herring after all.